# How to use var in pine script?

Tags: pine-script, var, indicator

This is an indicator:

```
//box 
boxp=input(5, "BOX LENGTH")
LL = lowest(low,boxp)
k1=highest(high,boxp)
k2=highest(high,boxp-1)
k3=highest(high,boxp-2)
NH =  valuewhen(high>k1[1],high,0)
box1 =k3<k2
TopBox = valuewhen(barssince(high>k1[1])==boxp-2 and box1, NH, 0)
BottomBox = valuewhen(barssince(high>k1[1])==boxp-2 and box1, LL, 0)
```

and I use variable:
var longstopprice = BottomBox[0]

but it isn't available to display the value when I plot longstopprice.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var` is the keyword used for assigning and one-time initializing of the variable.

When you do `longstopprice = BottomBox[0]`, it will initialize ´longstopprice`with the value of`BottomBox` on the **very first bar** and it will never change its value unless you explicitly do that.

It will take `BottomBox` several bars to get any none `na` value because you are using functions like `highest()` and `barssince()`.

If you plot `BottomBox`, you will see that it will take a few bars until it gets a valid number value.

[image]